# Packaging Android libraries with dependencies

Tags: android, sdk, dependencies

I'm creating an Android library that has another library in form of jar file as a dependency; I want to combine those two library in single jar file and send it to clients. 
I've tried adding the dependency jar to my Android Dependencies and my classpath but nothing seems to work. When I get my generated jar file from bin folder, it doesn't contain the second jar file inside.

Do you know if that's even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: by sdk do you mean a library or jar ? you will need to elaborate more for more people to respond.

Comment: Edited, you're right, it was impossible to understand :(

Comment: did you copy the dependent `jar` to `libs` folder of your project ? If you did, eclipse will automatically export/copy it [please see this for detials](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects).

Comment: I did, but in the resulting jar there's no reference to the dependent jar.

Comment: Are you using proguard? proguard deletes unused code with some configurations.